# Git when to commit, push and pull

Tags: git

While using `git` in a collective environment, in which several team members are working on the same project, when would be the "best" time to `commit`, `push` and `pull` so that one does not make other team members angry due to discrepancies etc.

And when there is discrepancies, how would someone solve it so that everyone in the same team would be satisfied while `diff`ing?

I hope someone can share the experiences and thoughts in regards to this.

Answer (score 2):

Commit often and short pieces of code, use proper commit messages. When you have a complete feature implemented `git rebase -i` and reorder/make commits look nicer then pull the code, rebase your commits on top of that (**with care**, see discussion in comments and chat) and push.

Comment: Why to rebase actually?

Comment: A linear history is nicer with `git bisect`.

Comment: @Mihai Maruseac: but then if there is a logic bug caused by rebase merge - you won't have the original source of it. It will look like it's you who made the terrible mistake.

Comment: @Unheilig: have you tried to google? Why haven't you?

Comment: I think we have different views on the term `rebase`. I'm speaking about http://techblog.rosedu.org/git-useful-aliases.html#rebase-instead-of-merge

Comment: @Mihai Maruseac: no, I understand what is rebase. It's rewriting the history with original history loss. So if after the automatic merge something bad will happen - you won't be able to find the reason of why it has happened.

Comment: I speak about rebasing when there's no conflict. If there's a merge conflict you still need a merge commit :)

Comment: @Mihai Maruseac: if there is no conflicts - it doesn't mean the automatic merge cannot introduce some logical bug. How to start a chat here to quickly give an example to you :-S

Comment: http://pastebin.com/19GWPY45 - here is a brief example of what can happen. This exact example may not work due to merge conflict but if it's strongly required I can provide an example that is reproducible with the latest git.

Comment: In both cases you get the same conflict and have to solve it when pulling :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52638/discussion-between-mihai-maruseac-and-zerkms)